# Angular DOM Manipulation broken after upgrading Angular 7 to 10

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I updated my working electron angular project from Angular 7 to Angular 10, updated all the dependencies, and ran the project.

I have two components that have the exact same HTML parent component. What I noticed was that after navigation to a second component, it only finds the DOM parent element of the previous component before navigation. This is not good because I am trying to dynamically update that specific DOM element.

For example, in component 1, the parent element is `<div _ngcontent-bsf-c106="" class="ph-header">...</div>`

For Component 2: `<div _ngcontent-bsf-c105="" class="ph-header">...</div>`

As shown, the only difference between the two elements is the attribute `_ngcontent-bsf-c10x`. This is automatically generated by Angular through [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) for both components. I route to component 2 using Angular routerLink.

```
      <a routerLink="/createtask" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa fa-plus"></i></a>
```

In component 2, I run a simple console log to get the element.

```
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('ph-header')[0])
```

**Expected Result:**

```
<div _ngcontent-bsf-c105="" class="ph-header">...</div>
```

**Actual Result:**

```
<div _ngcontent-bsf-c106="" class="ph-header">...</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is a routing issue or something else, as my project was working before I upgraded to Angular 10.

I did, however, have to make a change to my app.routing.ts to satisfy type errors.

**Before:**

```
 export const routing : ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

**After:**

```
 export const routing : ModuleWithProviders<any> = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

**Component 1 HTML:**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

</head>

<body id="main-body">
  <div class="ph-page">
    <div class="ph-sidebar">
  <div class="ph-sidebar-icon">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.png">
  </div>

  <a routerLink="/dashboard" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-chart-line"></i></a>
  <a routerLink="/createtask" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  <a routerLink="/profiles" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-credit-card"></i></a>
  <a routerLink="/captcha" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a>
  <a routerLink="/proxies" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-heart-rate"></i></a>
  <a routerLink="/logs" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-clock"></i></a>
  <a routerLink="/sales" class="ph-sidebar-item ph-selected"><i class="fal fa-money-check-edit-alt"></i></a>
  <a routerLink="/settings" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-cog"></i></a>
</div>
          <div class="ph-page-content">
      <div class="ph-header">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/120/000000/user--v1.png" id="discord-avatar" alt="avatar" class="ph-avatar">
        <div class="ph-icon-large ph-fade" id="bell" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="changeNotifStatus();"><i class="far fa-bell-slash"></i></div>
        <div class="ph-bubble-group">
          <div class="ph-bulb ph-bulb-green ph-bulb-large"></div>
          <div id="task-number">0 tasks</div>
          <div class="ph-bulb ph-bulb-yellow ph-bulb-large"></div>
          <div id="proxy-number">0 proxies</div>
          <div class="ph-bulb ph-bulb-large"></div>
          <div id="task-proxy-ratio">0:0 ratio</div>
        </div>
        <th style="margin-left: auto;">Dashboard</th>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Component 2 HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ph-page">
    <div class="ph-sidebar">
      <div class="ph-sidebar-icon">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png">
      </div>

      <a routerLink="/dashboard" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-chart-line"></i></a>
      <a routerLink="/createtask" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <a routerLink="/profiles" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-credit-card"></i></a>
      <a routerLink="/captcha" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a>
      <a routerLink="/proxies" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-heart-rate"></i></a>
      <a routerLink="/logs" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-clock"></i></a>
      <a routerLink="/sales" class="ph-sidebar-item ph-selected"><i class="fal fa-money-check-edit-alt"></i></a>
      <a routerLink="/settings" class="ph-sidebar-item"><i class="fal fa-cog"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="ph-page-content">
      <div class="ph-header">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/120/000000/user--v1.png" id="discord-avatar" alt="avatar" class="ph-avatar">
        <div class="ph-icon-large ph-fade" id="bell" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="changeNotifStatus();"><i class="far fa-bell-slash"></i></div>
        <div class="ph-bubble-group">
          <div class="ph-bulb ph-bulb-green ph-bulb-large"></div>
          <div id="task-number">0 tasks</div>
          <div class="ph-bulb ph-bulb-yellow ph-bulb-large"></div>
          <div id="proxy-number">0 proxies</div>
          <div class="ph-bulb ph-bulb-large"></div>
          <div id="task-proxy-ratio">0:0 ratio</div>
        </div>
        <th style="margin-left: auto;">Sales Center</th>
      </div>

      <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr; grid-gap: 2rem; height: 90%;">
        <div class="ph-block-fade" style="height: 100%;">
          <div class="ph-well" id="ph-well" style="height: 100%;">
          <div class="ph-well-stack" id="ph-well-stack">
            <div class="ph-well" id="ph-well-1" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="Window.createTaskComponent.profileClick(this)" value="1">
              <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr; grid-gap: 2rem; height: 100%;">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                  <img src="assets/img/amazon.png" style="width: 100%; height: 60%; border-radius: 1rem; border: 6px outset #18181d;">
                  <div class="ph-status-card-icon ph-red" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
                    <i class="far fa-times-circle" style="font-size: 2rem;"><span><th style="font-size: 1rem;"><br>Logged In</th></span></i>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                  <div class="ph-form-label" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 1rem;" translate>Amazon Seller Central</div>
                  <div class="ph-form-label" translate>Account</div>
                  <div class="ph-form-group-h">
                    <div>
                      <input type="text" class="ph-input" placeholder="Username" id="account-input">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <input type="text" class="ph-input" placeholder="Password" id="account-input">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ph-block" style="height: 60%;">
          <div class="ph-well" id="ph-well" style="height: 100%;">
          <div class="ph-well-stack" id="ph-well-stack">
            <div class="chart-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Component 2 TS:**

```
    import {
    Component,
    OnInit,
    NgZone,
    OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component2',
    templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    
    constructor() {
        Window["dashboardComponent"] = this;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('ph-header')[0])

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a template reference for each one with different names, and access them via `ViewChild`?

Comment: use hook `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`

Comment: I tried that and it does not change anything. Perhaps changing the class name in the second HTML file will resolve this issue?